# Please help me for my dell

Tags: drivers

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
so, I need a graphic driver for my laptop.
what can I do?
How can I do?
Please help me...

My laptop model : Dell Inspiron 14 7447
CPU : Core i7
RAM : 8 GB
Graphic : nVIDIA GEFORCE GTX Driver

Answer (score 2):

You can go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

and install a driver there.

Or run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

in terminal.

Comment: which one is the best and stable for my driver... Bumblebee and you said that nvidia -352

Comment: nVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M Graphics Driver < It is my graphic driver...